# readline-sync doesn't use right encoding on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I'm using [readline-sync](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync) to ask users of my noedejs commandline app for some information.
In my linux terminal, everything works fine with german umlauts (öäü) but when reading input on a windows shell (either powershell or cmd) it butchers my input despite having set the encoding to `utf8`:

```
var rls = require('readline-sync');
// set encoding for rls:
rls.setDefaultOptions({encoding: 'utf8'});
```

...

```
var test = rls.question("Input name: ");
console.log("Created: " + test);
```

Output on windows:

```
PS > tim test
Input name: töst
Created: t�st
```

It's also pretty interesting that parameters I pass to my app via commandline args will have the right characters.

Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have same problem here (2019)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way of getting this module to read accents from a Windows terminal correctly. But I noticied that the default module [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) does not have this type of problem.

So I made this workaround for the method `question`:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const question = question => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        rl.question(question, answer => {
            rl.close();
            return resolve(answer);
        });
    });
};

async function main() {
    const answer = await question('Enter your text with accents: ');
    console.log(answer);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

For another methods like `keyInSelect` you can use this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

This one would fix the display of special chars but the **issue remains on input retrieved values**.

The `console.log()` method does'nt have the issue with special chars may I suggest you to use it for displaying your message containing those.

Then you can simply move the cursor to the end of that message before displaying a single char with a `readlineSync.question()` or `readlineSync.keyInYN()` method.

This is a short example :

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
const readline = require('readline');

console.log('é€^¨$%');
readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, 8, -1); // moves cursor to the previous line at position 8

let answer = readlineSync.question(' ?');
```

Note that in order for this to work you'll need to have the `readline-sync` module installed.

You can install it by running that command :

```
npm install readline-sync
```

**EDIT :** 
**Use the node readline module like readline-sync without encoding issues** 
After looking at the example of the [rl.question(query[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_options_callback) method used as it's util.promisify()ed version in the NodeJS documentation.

You could simply use the `readline` module like you would have done with the `readline-sync` module without the encoding issue you encounter with `readline-sync`.

Here is how to do it :

First you need to add this in your file :

```
const readline = require('readline');
const util = require('util');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const question = util.promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);
```

Then you can ask questions like this :

```
async function questionExample() {
  try {
    const answer = await question('What is you favorite food? ');
    console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
    return answer;

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Question rejected', err);
    return err;
  }
}
```

You will also need your `main function` to be `async` as well so you can ask your questions like this :

```
async function main() {
    let firstAnswer = await questionExample();
    console.log(`My first answer : ${firstAnswer}`);
    rl.close();  
};

main();
```